# Making bracha when passing by a bakery

Tags: blessing, bread, smell

I've heard before that one should make a bracha when passing by a bakery that has a pleasant smell of what's being baked. What is the source for this halacha? What is the custom in this, do we yes make a bracha or not? If not (and the halacha says yes to) then why not?

Answer (score 1):

In Mishna Brurah 216:54... The discussion is brought (see Shulchan Aruch and Rama) whether a bracha is said when one smells hot bread and what nusach is said (rayach tov...bpeiros ...bpas) it seems since it is a safek we try not to intentionally smell breads or cakes for pleasure in order to take ourself out of a safek which is at hand.

Comment: Why are you quoting the Mishna Berurah when this is all in the Shulchan Arukh? I don't see where the Mishna Berurah adds anything of relevance to this question...

Comment: Because he holds not to make a bracha

Comment: See Mishna Brurahs 54,55,56.56 says even if you smell don't make a bracha